# Async await is not waiting for the cypress command to run

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using `async await` I would like to wait for some time before running the commands in cypress. But for some reason the below code is not waiting. Could someone please advise on the issue here ?

```
(async function doWaitForDialogOpen() {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 4000));
   cy.get('#iframeID0').then(($iframe)=>{    
     Cypress.$($iframe).find('html').find('body').find('#someId').find('input').type(100);
   })
  await doWaitForDialogOpen();
 })();
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to using async/await?

Comment: Sorry I haven't find one..

Answer (score 2):

Cypress has `wait` method, which will wait for given time. For more info [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Syntax)

Example:

```
(async function doWaitForDialogOpen() {
    await cy.wait(4000) // waits 4 seconds
    const $iframe = await cy.get('#iframeID0')
    Cypress.$($iframe)
   .find('html')
   .find('body')
   .find('#someId')
   .find('input')
   .type(100);
  // Do your next steps
 })();
```

Comment: Yes I know that, but I would like to try the async way of waiting.

Comment: `cy.wait`'s return a promise, you can use async before `wait`

Comment: Notice the `await` before `cy.get(…)`, which is missing in the original.

Comment: Even `cy.get` return's a promise